# Random variable proof of indicator function

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have a random variable  $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$  and $a>0$.
How can I show that the function $Y : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by
$$    Y(\omega) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        X(\omega), & \text{if }|X(\omega)| \leq  a \\
        0, & \text{if }|X(\omega)| >  a 
        \end{array}\right\}
 $$

is a random variable ?

Comment: Why the question?  It is defined in terms of a random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set, and put $A=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:|\vec{x}|\leq a\}$. Then $Y^{-1}(A^c)=\emptyset$ since $|Y(\omega)|\leq a$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$.

Note that $E$ is a disjoint union of the two measurable sets $E\cap A$ and $E\cap A^c\subseteq A^c$ so $$Y^{-1}(E)=Y^{-1}(E\cap A)\cup Y^{-1}(E\cap A^c)=X^{-1}(E \cap A)$$ which is measurable.